# Java - How can I create an array of a different class and iterate through it calling its toString method?

Tags: java

I have a Person class with the fields "name" and "phoneNumber" that are set through the constructor. I am trying to create a separate testing class that will create an array of Person and iterate through them by calling to their toString() method.
I am not sure how to do this, any help is appreciated.

Here is my first class which is all I have so far;

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Person(String name, String phoneNumber)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getNumber()
    {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getPerson()
    {
        return name + " " + phoneNumber;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "["+getPerson()+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: The testing class needs to be a list or other iterable collection that implants iterable<Person>. From there it's just a matter of creating the array of Persons and doing a for each loop to print it out however you choose.

Comment: Exactly which part of the assignment are you having trouble with?  Creating the array? Adding some `Person`s into the array?  Iterating over the `Person`s in the array? Calling `toString()`?  Creating the testing class which will do all that?

Comment: Show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person array[] = {new Person("Jason", "123456"), new Person("Karl", "78945"), new Person("Tom", "789456")};

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i].toString();
            //System.out.println(array[i].toString());
        }
    }

}

class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Person(String name, String phoneNumber)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getNumber()
    {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getPerson()
    {
        return name + " " + phoneNumber;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "["+getPerson()+"]";
    }
}
```

Save the file as Test.java

Answer (score -1):

Firstly the toString method is for an INDIVIDUAL Person object, and cannot be applied to a whole set, you need to make the method static and have a whole static array defined in the class to be able to go through all instances of the Person class.

```
private static Person[] pArray = new Person[20]; 
//I picked 20 randomly, if you want any possible number use an arrayList<Person> 

private static int count = 0;
```

In the constructor

```
pArray[count] = this;
count++;
```

Then your toString method:

```
String list = "[";
for(Person p : this.pArray)
   list = list + p.getPerson() + " ,"
list = list + "]";
return list;
```